# Escaping singlequote in random filenames

Tags: bash, disk-access

I have a simple bash script which outputs the total file size using 'du'
However every time I pass a file that contains an apostrophe it presents me with a syntax error.
So I'd like to know if there was a way to escape singlequotes without modifying the filenames. Preferably before diskusage processes them.

The code is:

```
du -chs {query}
```

I use Alfred to pass the files into the script. The application allows the user to escape a few characters but the single quote is not one of them.

Comment: Just show us a sample code of exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrap the file names in double quotes, that seems to work for me:

With a file named `hello'world` among a few others:

```
du -chs hello*
```

Gives:

```
4.0K    hello.RST
4.0K    hello.txt
4.0K    hello'world
12K     total
```